# I trying on php artisan in mac os but like this , how to solve?

Tags: php, laravel, macos, homebrew

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg-xl/lib/libjxl.0.7.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6

Comment: `php artisan ... what?` What is the full command that generates this output?

Answer (score 1):

The application you are trying to run/load depends on JPEG XL.

It appears JPEG XL is not installed or configured correctly.

To solve your problem, install JPEG XL and configure appropriately.